# How to initialize the weights of different layers of nn.Sequential block in different styles in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's suppose I have a `nn.Sequential` block, it has 2 linear layers. I want to initialize the weights of first layer by uniform distribution but want to initialize the weights of second layer as constant 2.0.

```py
net = nn.Sequential()
net.add_module('Linear_1', nn.Linear(2, 5, bias = False))
net.add_module('Linear_2', nn.Linear(5, 5, bias = False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing so:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn 

net = nn.Sequential()

ll1 = nn.Linear(2, 5, bias = False)
torch.nn.init.uniform_(ll1.weight, a=0, b=1) # a: lower_bound, b: upper_bound
net.add_module('Linear_1', ll1)
print(ll1.weight)

ll2 = nn.Linear(5, 5, bias = False)
torch.nn.init.constant_(ll2.weight, 2.0)
net.add_module('Linear_2', ll2)
print(ll2.weight)

print(net)
```

Output:

```
Parameter containing:
tensor([[0.2549, 0.7823],
        [0.3439, 0.4721],
        [0.0709, 0.6447],
        [0.3969, 0.7849],
        [0.7631, 0.5465]], requires_grad=True)

Parameter containing:
tensor([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]], requires_grad=True)

Sequential(
(Linear_1): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=5, bias=False)
(Linear_2): Linear(in_features=5, out_features=5, bias=False)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you define your module, you can do it by e.g.:

```
torch.nn.init.constant_(net.Linear_1.weight, 0.0)
torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_(net.Linear_2.weight)
```

for initializing different layers with different types of initializations.